# Efficiency of data structures in C99 (possibly affected by endianness)

Tags: c, performance, c99, endianness

I have a couple of questions that are all inter-related. Basically, in the algorithm I am implementing a word `w` is defined as four bytes, so it can be contained whole in a `uint32_t`.

However, during the operation of the algorithm I often need to access the various parts of the word. Now, I can do this in two ways:

```
uint32_t w = 0x11223344;
uint8_t a = (w & 0xff000000) >> 24;
uint8_t b = (w & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
uint8_t b = (w & 0x0000ff00) >>  8;
uint8_t d = (w & 0x000000ff);
```

However, part of me thinks that isn't particularly efficient. I thought a better way would be to use union representation like so:

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        uint8_t d;
        uint8_t c;
        uint8_t b;
        uint8_t a;
    };
    uint32_t n;
} word32;
```

Using this method I can assign `word32 w = 0x11223344;` then I can access the various 
parts as I require (`w.a=11` in little endian).

However, at this stage I come up against endianness issues, namely, in big endian systems my struct is defined incorrectly so I need to re-order the word prior to it being passed in.

This I can do without too much difficulty. My question is, then, is the first part (various bitwise ands and shifts) efficient compared to the implementation using a union? Is there any difference between the two generally? Which way should I go on a modern, x86_64 processor? Is endianness just a red herring here?

I could inspect the assembly output of course, but my knowledge of compilers is not brilliant. I would have thought a union would be more efficient as it would essentially convert to memory offsets, like so:

```
mov eax, [r9+8]
```

Would a compiler realise that is what happening in the bit-shift case above?

If it matters, I'm using C99, specifically my compiler is clang (llvm).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you measured the performance? Is the code which access this data structure critical in terms of performance? How different are the two approaches in terms of performance?

Comment: No not yet. I was wondering which way to implement, you see. Basically it's an implementation of AES I'm building, so yes it is critical. I can either invert the endianness of the entire data array and revert it at the end or I can do lots of bit shifting operations. Which is more efficient depends on the compiler, which is what I don't know. I may well simply have to measure both ways, we shall see.

Comment: why don't you read some open source code that does this and see how they do it. Even better would be to use an existing implementation.

Comment: @David I've seen both used, hence the question. And I would use somebody else's implementation if I actually wanted to use AES; the point was to implement the code as an exercise. I had to do a lot of background reading (Galois Fields, polynomials etc related to my current course). I simply want to prove to myself I can implement it. Then I stumbled across this and couldn't for the life of me work out which would be more efficient, or, for that matter, which I preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need AES, why not use an existing implementation? This can be particularly beneficial on modern Intel processors with hardware support for AES.

The union trick can slow down things due to store-to-load-forwarding (STLF) failures. This may happen, depending on the processor model, if you write data to memory and read it back soon as a different data type (e.g. 32bit vs 8bit).

Comment: Not only that, but...  Well, I don't know what kind of background @Ninefingers has, but I know I wouldn't trust myself to write my own crypto.  There are probably lots of AES implementations out there that have had a lot of scrutiny.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer although to be honest all of them have been helpful, because it mentions a specific drawback of unions. I had wondered why I'd not seen unions more widely used - this, along with C++, must be why. @asveikau Mathematical. I can read and understand most of what FIPS-197 says. I wanted to build an implementation to see it working in practice.

Comment: @asveikau I'm also aware there are other factors in cryptography such as timing based attacks and memory-based attacks. There's a famous quote somewhere about not needing to break a cryptosystem because most implementations are weak - I have not forgotten it. IANASE... I am not a security engineer?? In any case, don't worry, if I was actually using AES for real world purposes I'd use somebody else's code. Quite apart from anything else, I wouldn't be reinventing the wheel for run of the mill stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Such a thing is hard to tell without being able to inspect the real use of these operations in your code:

- the shift version will probably do
  better if you happen to have all your
  variables in registers, anyhow, and
  then you do intensive computations on
  them. Usually compilers (clang including) are relatively clever in issuing instructions for partial words and stuff like that.
- the union version would perhaps be
  more efficient if you'd have to load
  your bytes from memory most of the
  time

In any case I would abstract the access operation into a macro, such that you can modify it easily whence you have a working code.

For my personal taste I would go for the shift version, since it is conceptually simpler, and only go for the `union` when I'd see that at the end the produced assembler doesn't look satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess using a union may be more efficient. Of course, the compiler may be able to optimize the shifts into byte loads since they are known during compilation -- in which case both schemes will yield identical code.

Another option (also byte order dependent) is to cast the word to a byte array and access the bytes directly. I.e., something like the following

```
uint8_t b = ((uint8_t*)w)[n]
```

I'm not sure you will see any difference on a real modern 32/64 bit processor, though.

*EDIT*: It seems like clang produces identical code in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Given that accessing bits using shift and masking is a common operation I'd expect compilers to be quite smart about it especially if you're using constant shift count and mask.

An option would be to use macros for bit set/get so that you can pick the best strategy at configure time if on a specific platform a compiler happens to be on the dumb side (and wisely chosen names for the macros can also make the code more clear and self explaining).

Comment: Interesting idea. I might well take a look at the output (assembly) when I have more time and see what's going on. +1 from me.